# Android Retrofit with Rx get other http code

Tags: java, android, retrofit

i want to get other http code data same 400 , 401 and other with retrofit rx 
its my code

```
@GET("sample")
Observable<String> getSample();
```

&

```
public Observable<String> getSample() {
    return Domain.getApiClient(Tags.WRITHE_URL).getSample()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

&

```
   new AppStore().getSample().subscribe(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(String value) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

when http code 200 i can use data in on next
and other http code call on error 
in onError i dont have access data of server
what should i do for get data when http code is other than 200?

Comment: Instead of `String` you can use `Observable<ResponseBody>` (or `Response`? something like this) then you get the raw-ish response in onNext

Answer (score 0):

non-200 response information is included in the exception passed to `onError`:

```
  public void onError(Throwable e){
        HttpException error = (HttpException)e; //you can use the instanceof check
        int errorCode = error.response().code();
        String errorBody = error.response().errorBody().string();
 }
```

Comment: HttpException just have .getStatusCode()
are you try this?

Comment: use `HttpException` from the `retrofit2` package: `retrofit2.HttpException`